# Joomla Development Publish / unpublish not working

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a simple component following the hello world tutorial for the most part, and everything works except i've added a publish / unpublish icons to the toolbar and to the list itself (the small green / red circles).

The toolbar icons work and they can change the state no problem, but the small icons do not, here is the code I have:

**view.html.php:**

```
 protected function addToolBar() 
  {
    JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('COM_MADS_MANAGER_OBJECTS'));
    JToolBarHelper::publishList($task = 'objects.publish', $alt = 'Publish');
    JToolBarHelper::unpublishList($task = 'objects.unpublish', $alt = 'Unpublish');
    JToolBarHelper::deleteListX('', 'objects.delete');
    JToolBarHelper::editListX('object.edit');
    JToolBarHelper::addNewX('object.add');
  }
```

**tmpl > body:**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<?php foreach($this->items as $i => $item): ?>
  <tr class="row<?php echo $i % 2; ?>">
  <td><?php echo $item->id; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo JHtml::_('grid.id', $i, $item->id); ?></td>
  <td><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mads&task=object.edit&id=' . $item->id); ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a></td>
  <td><?php echo $item->description; ?></td>  
  <td align="center"><?php $published = JHTML::_('grid.published', $item, $i); echo $published;?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am using the built in publish / unpublish function and did not create one of my own.

**Tables:**

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.database.table');

class MAdsTableObjects extends JTable
{
    var $id = null;
    var $title = null;
    var $description = null;
    var $published = 0;


  function __construct(&$db) 
  {
    parent::__construct('#__mads_objects', 'id', $db);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: how does your table structure look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after A LOT OF FREKIN HEADACHE and wasted time, it should be:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.published', $item->published, $i, 'objects.',true); ?>
```

where **objects.** is the name of my view / controller / model for the listing.

Comment: i fixed this by adding method publish in component table (administrator/components/com_blog/tables/BlogTableBlog.php) You can use the method from weblinks component as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have a state field in the db, to store the status

```
state   tinyint(3)
```

Than try using:

```
 echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'JSTATUS', 'a.state', $listDirn, $listOrder);
```

Comment: There is already a published field in the db, 1 = on 0 = off, that's how the toolbar is working. Problem is the buttons are not. FYI, that wasn't me with the -1.

Comment: try changing the name to state.